# MemSQL select query 1705 error

Tags: singlestore

I am using memsql community version and I am able to execute some queries but getting error for few queries like

```
select * from policy; 
Error code:
ERROR 1705 (HY000): The query cannot be executed.
MemSQL code generation has failed: Failed to delete .fin file.
```

Answer (score 1):

This likely indicates a permissions problem or some other issue with your installation ([install dir]/plancache may not be writable by memsqld for example).  Did you install and start MemSQL via Ops?

There will probably be a more detailed error message inside of
[install dir]/tracelogs/memsql.log